# Analog clock app state stopping when submitting form

Tags: reactjs, state

I am working on this React app to make an Analog Clock with optional Inputs available to the user to change the color of the clock hands, clock border, etc.

But when I try to press the submit button sometimes, the second hand stops moving all of a sudden and seems like the 'time' states are not changing. The colors however do always change as intended so color states do change.

I tried to incorporate preventDefault() but it's a no go...

The first code snippet is defining the hooks, second is the form and third is the main App js file. I didn't include the JS/CSS files that include the transform and styling info.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
 
export const useInterval = (callback, delay) => {
    const savedCallback = useRef()

    // Remembers latest callback
    useEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback
    }, [callback])

    //Set-up the interval
    useEffect(() => {
        const tick = () => {
            savedCallback.current()
        }
        if (delay !== null) {
            let id = setInterval(tick, delay)
            return () => clearInterval(id)
        }
    }, [delay])
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './CustomForm.css';;

function CustomForm(props) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState(props.defaultOptions)

    const setClockColor = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let clockColors = { ...options.clockColors };
        clockColors[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        setOptions({ ...options, clockColors });
    }

    const buildClock = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(() => props.updateClock(options), 1000);
        
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={(event) => buildClock(event)}>
            <div className='custom-title'>Custom Analog Clock </div>
            <div className='all-hand-color-container'>
                <div className='input-label-container'>
                    <input className='color-input' placeholder='Second-color' label='Second Hand Color' name='second' type='text' onChange={setClockColor} />
                </div>
                <div className='input-label-container'>
                    <input className='color-input' placeholder='Minute-color' label='Minute Hand Color' name='minute' type='text' onChange={setClockColor} />
                </div>
                <div className='input-label-container'>
                    <input className='color-input' placeholder='Hour-color' label='Hour Hand Color' name='hour' type='text' onChange={setClockColor} />
                </div>
                <div className='input-label-container'>
                    <input className='color-input' placeholder='Border-color' label='Border Color' name='border' type='text' onChange={setClockColor} />
                </div>
                <div className='input-label-container'>
                    <input className='color-input' placeholder='Base-color' label='Base Color' name='base' type='text' onChange={setClockColor} />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='custom-submit-button-container'>
                <button  className='custom-submit-button' type='submit'>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        

    )
}

export default CustomForm;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useInterval } from './Hook';
import { ClockBase, Center, SecondHand, MinuteHand, HourHand } from './Components';
import CustomForm from './CustomForm';
import './App.css'


const App = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0)
    const [hours, setHours] = useState(0)

    const [options, setOptions] = useState({
        clockColors: {
            second: 'green',
            minute: 'blue',
            hour: 'red',
            border: 'gray',
            base: 'black'
        }
    })

    const updateClock = (new_options) => {
        setOptions({ ...new_options });
    }


    useInterval(() => {
        setSeconds(date.getSeconds())
        setMinutes(date.getMinutes())
        setHours(date.getHours() % 12 || 12)
    }, 1000 )
    
    return(
        
        <div className='main-container'>
            <h1 className='form-container'>
                <CustomForm defaultOptions={options} updateClock={updateClock} />
            </h1> 
            <div className='clock-container'>
                <ClockBase color={options}>
                    <Center />
                    <SecondHand fraction={seconds} color={options}/>
                    <MinuteHand fraction={minutes} color={options}/>
                    <HourHand fraction={hours} color={options}/>
                </ClockBase>
            </div>
        </div>

        
    )
}



export default App;
```

Comment: I am not sure why need 1000 ms delay inside setTimeout of buildClock function?

Comment: I thought the delay would fix the issue but looks like it doesn't